# ffmpeg : drop in sound multiple times at random intervals

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I have a 2 MP3 files, one is 10 minutes long and another track that is 1 second long. I would like to merge these tracks into a new file that plays the 1 second track at random intervals of the longer one.

Answer (score 0):

processA ... split the longer file into several segments using your random interval  for details see  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1675/10949

processB ... then for each segment from above splitting operation append your shorter file ...  repeat until you have each processA segment with that shorter file appended ... for details see https://superuser.com/a/1164761/81282

then stitch together all of above files from processB

I have not tried this however it might be easier if you first converted both original source mp3 files into WAV files before doing anything ... then once done and working as WAV convert the final WAV back to mp3